# COUNTIFS with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that works well

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(DR!$K:$K,"A",DR!$D:$D,{"B","N"},DR!$B:$B,{"IT","SU"}))
```

But there are situations where I might not have any data under a field, eg. SU. When this happens, my value is less then the correct value.

I can get the correct value if I change the formula to

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(DR!$K:$K,"A",DR!$D:$D,{"B","N"},DR!$B:$B,{"IT"}))
```

However, I would like a fixed formula since its for monthly use and not having to manually change it every month.

Any way to change the formula or some understanding of whats wrong?

Comment: I take it you're aware that the first formula you give is NOT counting all rows where any of the following FOUR combinations occurs: 1) The value in column D is "B" AND the value in column B is "IT"; 2) The value in column D is "B" AND the value in column B is "SU"; 3) The value in column D is "N" AND the value in column B is "IT"; 4) The value in column D is "N" AND the value in column B is "SU"? Rather it is counting all rows where these TWO only apply: 1) The value in column D is "B" AND the value in column B is "IT": 2) The value in column D is "N" AND the value in column B is "SU".

Comment: @XORLX just for my personal interest and because I don't understand that formula and I'm not an Excel formula noob (at least I think so). What do the brackets do `{"B","N"}` in combination with the `sum()`? Because without `sum` the "N" AND "SU" doesn't count! Any hint or resource would be nice to read.